# Android broke after eclipse update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-7

I updated eclipse, and android then started giving the error `Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.` adb.exe is in fact at that location and it can be executed. I have tried reinstalling the android sdk at that location, and reinstalling the android eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not able to post comments yet, I'll share with you some responses from other thread:

- Kill the **adb.exe** process located in Task Manager and then restart Eclipse.

If it does not work, try to reset adb in Devices. Clean up the project may would help too.

Comment: I restarted my computer and that fixed it. As restarting kills all processes, this may have been what caused it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. If it's not a huge inconvenient, would appreacite your approval of my answer. Have a nice day.